# My server coded in pyhon 3 does not send messages to all users

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tcp

I started learning socket programming in **Python 3** and I am trying to create a TCP chat server which can support multiple users but it is not working because the server does not send the message to all users, it sends it back the message only to the person who sent the message.

This is my server code (sorry for being a noob):

```
import socket
from _thread import *

sk = socket.socket()
sk.bind(('', 3000))
sk.listen(5)


def client(conn):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        mess = data.decode('utf-8')
        print(mess)
        conn.sendall(data)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("server started")
    while True:
        conn, id = sk.accept()
        print("{} conected".format(id))
        start_new_thread(client, (conn,))
```

and this is my client :

```
import socket
import threading

sk = socket.socket()
target_ip = input("ip : ")
port = int(input("port: "))
sk.connect((target_ip, port))

def send():
    mess = input()
    while mess != 'EXIT':
        mess = str.encode(mess)
        sk.send(mess)
        mess = input()




def listen():
        while True:
            data = sk.recv(1024)
            mess = data.decode('utf-8')
            if mess == 'zalinga':
                quit()
            else:
                print(mess)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = threading.Thread(target = send)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target = listen)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

I don't know where is the problem but I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you start your new thread to listen to the connection, you need to add that connection to some collection of connections.

When you receive data, instead of sending it to the socket that sent you the data, iterate over the collection and send the data to each socket in the list. Consider also sending at the same time the id of the socket, so you know who sent you the info.

Comment: how do i do that ?

Comment: like, how do i send data to each socket in the list ?

Comment: @Costelbiju At the top, define `all_sockets = []` then when you get a new connection,`all_sockets.append(sk)` and later when you go to send, `for socket in all_sockets: socket.sendAll(data)`

Comment: I am getting this error : OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

Comment: @Costelbiju *shrug* I dunno dude. I can't see your entire server, and to be truthful I'm not a python guy, I'm a Java guy. Could be that my line of `all_sockets.append(sk)` should actually be `all_sockets.append(conn)` - after all, sk is the server socket, and you want to be appending the client socket which is conn.